# Name format for com.docker.ucp.access.label for Docker EE deploy

Tags: docker, docker-ucp

Does anyone know the right label naming format assigned to com.docker.ucp.access.label field within compose yaml file?

At the moment, we are using label name as "app-examples".  Want to know if we can provide "100app-examples100".  Wanted to know what all chars are accepted as part of the label name.

Comment: Have you read through here? - https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps